# Merge two Dataframes with same columns with overwrite

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have dataframe like this:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({"flag":["1","0","1","0"], 
     "val":["111","111","222","222"], "qwe":["","11","","12"]})
```

It gives:

```
   flag qwe val
0    1      111
1    0  11  111
2    1      222
3    0  12  222
```

Then i am filtering first dataframe like this:

```py
    dff = df.loc[df["flag"]=="1"]
    **was:**
    dff.loc["qwe"] = "123"
    **edited:** (setting all rows in column "qwe" to "123")
    dff["qwe"] = "123"
```

And now i need to merge/join df and dff in such a way to get:

```
   flag qwe val
0    1  123 111
1    0  11  111
2    1  123 222
3    0  12  222
```

Adding changes in 'qwe' from dff only if df value is empty.

Something like this:

```py
pd.merge(df, dff, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left")
```

gives

```
    flag_x qwe_x val_x flag_y qwe_y val_y
0      1         111      1         111
1      0    11   111    NaN   NaN   NaN
2      1         222      1         222
3      0    12   222    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

so, after that i need to drop flag_y, val_y, rename _x columns and merge manually qwe_x and qwe_y. But is there any way to make it easier?

Comment: all you want to do is fill the blank spaces with `123` if `flag` is =`1` ? if that's the case then `df.loc[(df.flag == '1') & (df.qwe == ''), 'qwe'] = '123'` should do the trick.

Comment: 123 here is just an example. In fact there is a complex processing instead of simply setting 123.  Also, instead of flag==1 there is more complex multicolumn condition. So, i literally should add values from dff to df, not touching existing ones.

Comment: then we need to see a better representation of your data, show us a sample input/output. 5 rows of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After edited changes, for me works this code:

```py
c1 = dff.combine_first(df)
```

It produces:

```
   flag  qwe val
0    1  123  111
1    0   11  111
2    1  123  222
3    0   12  222
```

Which is exactly i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.merge` has an `on` argument that you can use to join columns with the same name in different dataframes.

Try:

```py
pd.merge(df, dff, how="left", on=['flag', 'qwe', 'val'])
```

However, I don't think you need to do that at all. You can produce the same result using df.loc to conditionally assign a value:

```py
df.loc[(df["flag"] == "1") & (df['qwe'].isnull()), 'qwe'] = 123
```

Comment: Be careful OP wants to add 123 only if there is nothing in the qwe columns. The second part of you answer doesn't take this into account

Comment: Thanks! Had missed that.

Comment: I wouldn't use `isnull()` either as it looks like he has blank spaces and not NaN's, why don't you convert the blank spaces to true null values for him first ? : )

Comment: for me merge does nothing - it just returns all rows from df with values from df but not from dff.